# expresso store - adding more items than in stock

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way to allow say 10 items to be added to a cart when there are are only 6 in stock and in the database the value of items is -4, therefore out of stock items can be added to the cart. Would like to keep inventory exact rather than unlimited but at the same time allow for orders that exceed the stock quantity

Additionally, providing user feedback stating that some items are out of stock when the shopping cart page is loaded?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in Store, if you are limiting the Stock level of an item you will only be able to add the in stock amount of items to the cart.